# When to use a class vs. module extending self in Crystal?

Tags: class, module, crystal-lang

In Crystal, there's two different ways to achieve similar results:

Creating a class...

```
class Service
  def self.get
    # ...
  end
end
```

or a module extending `self`:

```
module Service
  extend self

  def get
    # ...
  end
end
```

Both can invoke the method `get` by `Service.get`.

But when to use a class or a module? What's the difference between Crystal's classes and modules?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is not much difference between `class` and `module` regarding definition of class methods. They are however fundamentally different in the fact that a class defines a type that can be instantiated (`Service.new`). Modules can have instance methods as well, but they can't be instantiated directly, only included in a class.

If you only need a namespace for class methods, you should use `module`. `class` would work fine for this too, but conveys a different meaning.

Btw: While you can't `extend` or `include` a class, in a module you can write `def self.get` instead of `extend`.

Answer (score 3):

> But when to use a class or a module?

Use a `module`. In this way a `module` can be used as a namespace.

> What's the difference between Crystal's classes and modules?

A `module` cannot be instantiated, and can be included inside a class

See: [Modules documentation](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/modules.html)